NLua/KeraLua strict mode and .Net
I'm using NLua, an enhanced KeraLua. It integrates quite a lot of .Net framework to be used in Lua scripts.
I want to include some runtime checks if a user script variable is defined
a = b

should fail rather than beeing succesfull assigning nil to "a"
To achieve that I've added strict.lua from https://www.lua.org/extras/5.4/strict.lua.
This works great so that above script throws an error.
Unfortunatelly it also throws if a .Net class is used
ns = XNamespace.Get("")

el = XElement.Parse("<Bla><Grmpf></Grmpf></Bla>")
elGrmpf = el:Element(ns + "Grmpf")

Here it complains that XNamespace is not declared.
I can't add it in the metatable lua.strict creates as it would be treated as global variable
with the value null rather than the .Net component.
NLua has a function LoadCLRPackage() which does all the .Net Framework imports,but I don't see them in the global table _G
Where does NLua/KeraLua store the .Net Framework related names so that I can additionally check against those in lua.strict?
